In Excel, is it possible to refresh all the detail views created from a pivot table?
I know I can refresh the pivot table itself, and even all the pivot tables in a workbook.
But, what about the detail views generated from the pivot table? (when you double click on a value to see the underlying rows of data).
Now, I need to double click the appropriate cells again - and then get rid of the old detail views.
Is there a way to just get all of the detail views refreshed?  Maybe with VBA?

A detail view is just a new worksheet with the data copied to it. It's not a "child" of the pivot table. You might as well have created it manually.
